# ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python.alpine3.8:latest

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am new to Docker and learning how to creating an image in container but I am having this error  `ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python.alpine3.8.3:latest`

Please someone help me to fix this error!

```
FROM python.alpine3.8
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD python
```

The above is the code of Dockerfile

Comment: See this [Github issue](https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/476) for possible ways to address this errror.

Answer (score 1):

change docker `daemon.json` "buildkit" on the last line to FALSE, like so:

```
  {
        "builder": { "gc": { "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB", "enabled": true } },
        "experimental": false,
        "features": { "buildkit": false }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain what happens when you do this and why it fixes the problem.

Comment: to be honest I don't remember, has been so long, sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

The buildkit feature in Docker is still under development, and it can sometimes cause problems with proxy servers. By setting the buildkit feature to false, you can disable this feature and avoid the proxy error.